# Find the approved subsets of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: order-theory

We say that a subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is approved when $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ if $y \in A$ and $x \leq y$ then $x \in A$. I want to find all the approved subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $x,y \in A$ with $x \leq y$ and $y \in A$. If $x \in A$, doesn't it mean that the set of the $x$s is a subset of the set of $y$s.

But does this help somehow?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  An example of your set $A$ might be "all $x<0$".  Does that clarify things for you?

Comment: I'd say the set of approved sets is  the set of all intervals of the form $\;(-\infty,\,r)\,,\,\,r\in\Bbb R\;$ or $\;(-\infty,\,r]\,,\,\,r\in\Bbb R\;$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine all subsets of reals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3339194/determine-all-subsets-of-reals)

Comment: @DonAntonio Also $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{R}$ itself.

Comment: @Peter, true...though $\;\emptyset=(1,1)\;$

Comment: @DonAntonio What do you mean? You didn't state $(1,1)$ in any of your valid sets.

Comment: @PeterForeman True.

Comment: Just as a bit of terminology, subsets defined in this way (for any partial order) are called "downward-closed".

Answer (score 5):

Your definition seems to say that if $$y\in A$$ then $$(-\infty,y]\subset A.$$
To me this says that $A$ is either empty, all of $\mathbb R$, a set of the form $(-\infty,a)$, or a set of the form $(-\infty,a]$, and that these are the only possibilities.

This is because $$A=\bigcup_{a\in A}(-\infty,a].$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha=\sup A$. Then $(-\infty,\alpha)\subset A\subset(-\infty,\alpha]$, so $A$ is one of those two intervals, depending on whether $\alpha\in A$.

(Note this includes the case $\alpha=+\infty$, in which case $A=(-\infty,\infty)=\Bbb R$.)

(And, as pointed out by @MPW, it also includes $\alpha=-\infty$, which leads to $A=\varnothing$.)

Comment: It also includes the case $\alpha=-\infty$ (which occurs when $A=\varnothing), since all three of those sets are then empty. +1 for succinctness.

Comment: @MPW Indeed. $\emptyset$, the only set with $\sup<\inf$...